# Pass data from .NET Core console app to .NET Core web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, console-application

As the title says I need help or pointers on how I can pass data from my console app, that is running on a Raspberry Pi, to my web application. Im new too both programming and .NET Core so if you missing some information let me know.[Image to get a bigger picture of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3kpS.png)

Comment: you can use REST.... or gRPC.... or raw sockets..... or Actors...or queuing tech ...you can go via database, signalR...... or many other interprocess / networking protocols

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will dig in to that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is a REST (Http) call from the console app running on the Pi to the Web Application.

The below article should help

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1